# How to copy data from one table to another table based on criteria

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am new SQL and I want to copy certain rows from one table to other table based on certain criteria. Currently, what I am doing I am inserting data in the temp table and looping that table and assigning required fields to a variable and then inserting these rows into another table. But its look ambiguous. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More efficient way to update table is by joining the tables like below.

```
UPDATE
     Table1
SET
     Table1.col1 = Table2.col1,
     Table1.col2 = Table2.col2
FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.id
WHERE
    Table2.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create new records on other table then you can write like this

```
insert into employee1 (id, [name])
select id, [name] from employee2 where id >10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we have an example:

create table1

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [package_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [task_name] [varchar](50) NULL)
```

create table2

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table2](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [package_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [task_name] [varchar](50) NULL)
```

insert in table1

```
INSERT INTO table1 
VALUES ( 1, 'abc', 'def')
```

here we will select from table1 and insert into table2

```
INSERT INTO [table2] SELECT * FROM [table1]
```